# DATEDIFF and NOW() mysql_fetch_array error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm currently working on a script. When a user posts something and the timedifference is smaller than 5 minutes, the user cannot post. If bigger than 5 minutes, he can make a post. I thaught this code would work, but I get a mysql_fetch_array error. What is wrong with my code?

```
if ($db_found)
 {
 $check="SELECT * DATEDIFF(MINUTE, send_time, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) FROM bloopp WHERE email = '$email' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
 $res = mysql_query($check);
 $data = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_NUM);
  if($data[0] < 5)
   {
   echo "You posted not so long ago.<br/>";
   }
  else
   {
   $sql="INSERT INTO bloopp (bloopp, browser, medium, send_time, email) VALUES ('$bloopp', '$browser', 'mobile', NOW(), '$email')";
   $result = mysql_query($sql); 
    if($result)
     {
     header('Location: index.php');
     }
     else
     {
      echo "Something has gone wrong. We’re sorry.";
     }
    }
 }
else
 {
 echo "ERROR";
 }

mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Just an advice, do not use mysql_* functions. Use mysqli or PDO module. Check this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: If you want to get detailed information about an error when performing database operations, use mysql_error() function.

Also please remember that the functions you are using are deprecated and will be removed in future PHP versions. You can read more here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing with `,` right after `*`

```
SELECT * DATEDIFF(MINUTE, send_time, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

change to

```
SELECT * ,DATEDIFF(MINUTE, send_time, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS `diff`
```

*its better to give alias when your are making custom column in query*

Comment: Great! This already works, but how do I make the if-statement then? How do I refer to 'diff'? Like "$diff"?

Comment: @bloopp-it you can use `$data['diff']` by using `mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_ASSOC);` see reference here http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Comment: Works perfectly. Though I had to change something else (DATEDIFF had to be TIMESTAMPDIFF)!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  DATEDIFF(MINUTE, send_time, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Remove the *

Or keep it but add a comma after.